# Chrome.storge having issues even after defining the permissions in the manifest file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to store a value in chrome storage and want the function to be I want to store a value in chrome storage and want the function to be called in case of some event. But, the fucntion does not fire up and store any data in chrome storage. Is there a way out?
I have included my code snippet for the same.

```
var theValue = 'mystring';

function newToken(){
   theValue = prompt("enter uname");
}

function testChromeStorage() {
   if(theValue == 'mystring'){
      newToken(); 
      console.log("Saving");
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
         console.log('Settings saved');
      });
   } else {
      chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function (retVal) {
         console.log("Got it? " + retVal.value);
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: The code only declares the function and doesn't call it. To call a function do `testChromeStorage()`

Comment: the function is called in a later stage in my code. I think there is some issue in the given code snippet

Comment: The only possible issue here is that this code doesn't actually use the value it gets from the storage.